# Can a spark job use akka actors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can my spark job use the akka actor system or is that not possible and or a bad idea?

Can someone explain if it is a bad idea or not?

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is that you would need to serialize your actor to send it to each node in the cluster.  Actors are often used for things like sharing mutable state across threads, running in a single thread -- if the actor exists on every node in the cluster, that's not going to work.  It's probably hypothetically possible to use an actor in a spark operation, but I'm not sure what problem it would solve taking into account the limitations you'd face.